# Flutter web - Upload Image File to Firebase Storage

Tags: file-upload, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, image-upload, flutter-web

On flutter web, I pick an image file from the computer and get a File image object. Then I want to upload it to Firebase Storage. For Android and iOS versions of the app I was using a Firebase Cloud Function and an http multipart request. It worked, but for the web version of the app it doesn't. So,

How can I upload an html image file to Firebase Storage, either directly or through a Cloud Function?

Comment: I think you should be able to use Firebase Cloud Storage for Flutter # https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage

Comment: @RenaudTarnec That is the FlutterFire plugin, which only works for Android and iOS. For Web, use `firebase-dart`: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/tree/master/example/storage

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I managed to find a solution to this issue. To achieve this I needed to install two dependencies, [firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase) and [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html).
Yet difficult to find out the solution, its implementation was actually simple. Here is the code of the function I used to upload the html image file to Firebase Storage, into the "images" folder:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_universal/html.dart' as html;
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;

Future<Uri> uploadImageFile(html.File image,
      {String imageName}) async {
    fb.StorageReference storageRef = fb.storage().ref('images/$imageName');
    fb.UploadTaskSnapshot uploadTaskSnapshot = await storageRef.put(image).future;
    
    Uri imageUri = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return imageUri;
}
```

I hope it helps someone with the same need as me.

Comment: upload was success but not open. header?

Comment: How do you get the html.File?

Comment: @shinriyo I got the same problem, file corrupted. What should I do?

Comment: You made my day!
Thanks for the answer

Comment: Why import that universal_html library, when you can just use `import 'dart:html' as html;`?

Comment: Going of this answer, what worked for me is using [image_picker_for_web](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_for_web) to get the image. Then turning that image into base64 encoding and using ```putString``` instead of ```put``` like the above. More documentation on putString can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files)

Comment: Hi Prince Hodonou, can you please post an example thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20):

After Combining so many posts I did it, and it works!

No, you just don't need any Kind of Universal_HTML or another image_picker_web. Just stick with Image Picker(https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker).
And use the below code as I have used to upload the Image to Firebase Storage, and it works in all the way IOS, Android, Web, I hope you've already added the permission for ios and android. Let's Begin!

`Import`

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;
```

`Call this method when you want to open a file picker in any of the above platforms!`

```
chooseImage() async {
PickedFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
}
```

`now you've file in pickedFile use kIsWeb to find out if it's web or not!`

```
uploadImageToStorage(PickedFile? pickedFile) async {
if(kIsWeb){
Reference _reference = _firebaseStorage
        .ref()
        .child('images/${Path.basename(pickedFile!.path)}');
    await _reference
        .putData(
      await pickedFile!.readAsBytes(),
      SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg'),
    )
        .whenComplete(() async {
      await _reference.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
        uploadedPhotoUrl = value;
      });
    });
 }else{
//write a code for android or ios
}

}
```

Comment: This library  only works for iOS and Android. Web, which the OP is asking about, is not supported.

Answer (score 9):

## Answer for 2022

TLDR: Convert your files to XFiles using the [cross_file](https://pub.dev/packages/cross_file) package before uploading.

#### Select an Image

Use the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package to select an image. This works on Android, iOS, and the web.

```
Future<String?> selectPicture(ImageSource source) async {
  XFile? image = await imagePicker.pickImage(
    source: source,
    maxHeight: 1000,
    maxWidth: 1000,
  );

  return image?.path;
}
```

#### Convert the XFile to a Uint8List

```
String path = selectPicture(ImageSource.gallery);
Uint8List imageData = await XFile(path).readAsBytes()
```

#### Upload the Uint8List to Cloud Storage

```
UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putData(imageData);
```

Comment: worked well, thank you @Joe Muller. is there a typo in your answer? 'storageReference.putData(file);' should be 'storageReference.putData(imageData);'. for newbies (like me), you may need "import 'dart:typed_data';" to handle Uint8List.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the complete snip that work for me for uploading image:
`html.File` doesn't work for me, the file is uploaded but you will see `Error loading preview` in firebase storage, so just passing the bytes directly work for me.

To show an image you can use `mediaInfo.bytes` with widget that support bytes e.g `FadeInImage` you can use `MemoryImage(mediaInfo.bytes)` and `Image.memory(mediaInfo.bytes)`

packages used:

1. [firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase)
2. [image_picker_web](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_web)
3. [path](https://pub.dev/packages/path)
4. [mime_type](https://pub.dev/packages/mime_type)

```dart
    Future<MediaInfo> imagePicker() async {    
        MediaInfo mediaInfo = await ImagePickerWeb.getImageInfo;
        return mediaInfo;
     }
     
     Future<Uri> uploadFile(
          MediaInfo mediaInfo, String ref, String fileName) async {
        try {
          String mimeType = mime(Path.basename(mediaInfo.fileName));

          // html.File mediaFile =
          //     new html.File(mediaInfo.data, mediaInfo.fileName, {'type': mimeType}); 
          final String extension = extensionFromMime(mimeType);

          var metadata = fb.UploadMetadata(
            contentType: mimeType,
          );

          fb.StorageReference storageReference =
              fb.storage().ref(ref).child(fileName + ".$extension");

          fb.UploadTaskSnapshot uploadTaskSnapshot =
              await storageReference.put(mediaInfo.data, metadata).future;

          Uri imageUri = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
          print("download url $imageUri");
          return imageUri;
        } catch (e) {
          print("File Upload Error $e");
          return null;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

To access Cloud Storage in your Flutter for Web application, you can use the [`firebase-dart` plugin](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart). You can find an example of [accessing storage through `firebase-dart`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/tree/master/example/storage) in the repo.

Comment: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/tree/master/example/storage is not available

Comment: It now seems to be here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/tree/master/firebase/example/storage

Answer (score 3):

## Select an Image

Use the image_picker package to select an image.

```
Future<void> imgFromGallery() async {

    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    
    Uint8List imageData = await XFile(pickedFile!.path).readAsBytes();

    uploadImage(imageData );
}
```

## Upload to Cloud Storage

Use the UUID package to create a unique name.

```
 Future<String> uploadImage(Uint8List xfile) async {

    Reference ref = _storage.ref().child('Folder');
    String id = const Uuid().v1();
    ref = ref.child(id);

    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(
      xfile,
      SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/png'),
    );
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }
```

## Upload to Cloud Firestore

```
  Future<void> addData() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.('DBname').add({'image':downloadUrl});
      
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
     
    } catch (_) {
      
    }
  }
```

## Show image in the flutter ***Web App***

1. Open the [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), select your project and start a cloud terminal session by clicking the `>_` icon button in the top navbar.
2. Click the open editor button, then create the **cors.json** file and enter the code below and save it.

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

3. Open Terminal (Cloud Shell) and run the below code.

```
 gsutil cors set cors.json gs://your-bucket
```

**Note: replace your bucket id from firebase Storage**

4. Now make the Ui in the **Flutter Web App**

```
Image.network(widget.project.image!)
```

#### Note: Only if you have already set the following codes

web/index.html

```
<HTML>
....
<body>
<script type="module">

    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-storage.js";
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-firestore.js";
 
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "....",
    authDomain: "...",
    projected: "....",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "....",
    appId: "....",
    measurementId: "...."
  };
  
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
....
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 void uploadImage({required Function(File? file) onSelected}) {
    var uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement()..accept = 'image/*';
    uploadInput.click();

    uploadInput.onChange.listen((event) async {
      final file = uploadInput.files!.first;

      final reader = FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
      reader.onLoadEnd.listen((event) async {
        onSelected(file);
      });
    });
  }

  void uploadToStorage() {
    final dateTime = DateTime.now();
    final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    imagePath = '$userId/$dateTime'.replaceAll(' ', '');

    uploadImage(onSelected: (file) {
      try {
        fb.storage().refFromURL('{reference url from firebase}').child(imagePath).put(file);
      } catch (e) {
        print('uploadImage $e');
      }
    });
  }
```

Call uploadToStorage function on button click and to show the image,

```
 Future<Uri> downloadImageUrl(String? path) {
    print(
        'downloadImageUrl:: ${fb.storage().refFromURL('{reference url from firebase}').child(path!).getDownloadURL()}');
    return fb
        .storage()
        .refFromURL('gs://onehourappbuildpractice.appspot.com/')
        .child(path)
        .getDownloadURL();
  }

FutureBuilder<Uri>(
                      future: downloadImageUrl(
                          controller.hiddenGemList[i].imagePath!),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        }
                        return Container(
                            height: 100,
                            width: 200,
                            child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                              image: snapshot.data.toString(),
                              placeholder: 'assets/placeholder_image.jpeg',
                            ));
                      })
```

Comment: After many attempts, this was the one that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to [@WebRooseDevelopment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68185064) you may also need to update the index.html file to include the new firebase versions.

'`src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js">'`

Comment: (quoting and decoration are not properly nested)