# Store image uploaded by user into Flutter Web as an actual .jpg file

Tags: flutter, file-upload, flutter-web

I am using the [flutter_web_image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_image_picker) package to allow the user to select -and then upload to Firebase- an image.

However, the package returns an `image widget`, which I can display, but I cannot upload to Firebase. Therefore, I am trying to read the package's code and update it to fit my needs.

In general, I think the packages main functionalities are:

It gets the file

```dart
//...
final reader = html.FileReader();
reader.readAsDataUrl(input.files[0]);
await reader.onLoad.first;
final encoded = reader.result as String;
```

Then it 'strippes' it

```dart
final stripped = encoded.replaceFirst(RegExp(r'data:image/[^;]+;base64,'), '');
final imageName = input.files?.first?.name;
//...
```

To finally return it as a Widget:

```dart
final imageName = imageName;
final imageData = base64.decode(stripped);
return Image.memory(imageData, semanticLabel: imageName);
```

As I said, it works perfectly, however, I need to adapt it to my needs:

I would like to get the image as a `.jpg` file so that I can upload it to Firebase.

Is any of the variables above the actual `.jpg` file? Is there any transformation that I should perform to get a `.jpg` file?

Thanks!

Comment: convert it. There are many packages that can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I based my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716944/flutter-web-upload-image-file-to-firebase-storage) post.

Basically, on the [flutter_web_image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_image_picker) package, before the code I posted, there were a few lines that get an actual html file:

```dart
final html.FileUploadInputElement input = html.FileUploadInputElement();
input..accept = 'image/*';
input.click();
await input.onChange.first;
if (input.files.isEmpty) return null;
```

Then using firebase's pacakge, I uploaded the image as follow:

```dart
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
fb.StorageReference storageRef = fb.storage().ref('myLocation/filename.jpg'); 
fb.UploadTaskSnapshot uploadTaskSnapshot = await storageRef.put(input.files[0]).future;
    
Uri imageUri = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
return imageUri;
```