# Flutter web - Uploading image to firebase storage

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-web

I am using the `firebase_storage: ^8.0.6` package on flutter web. I want to upload image to firebase storage that I get using `FilePicker` package.
The problem is that the new package uses the putFile() method to upload files. But File from dart:io doesn't work on flutter web and it also doesn't accept the File object from dart:html.

I can upload image as Blob using the putBlob() method but then it doesn't upload it as image type but it's type is `application/octet-stream`. I don't want to upload the image file as a blob.

```
  Future<String> uploadImage(PlatformFile file) async {
    try {

      TaskSnapshot upload = await FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref(
              'events/${file.name}-${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}.${file.extension}')
          .putBlob(Blob(file.bytes));

      String url = await upload.ref.getDownloadURL();
      
      return url;
    } catch (e) {
      print('error in uploading image for : ${e.toString()}');
      return ';
    }
  }
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter web - Upload Image File to Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716944/flutter-web-upload-image-file-to-firebase-storage)

Comment: @DarShan The question uses put and i am using putFile which accepts file from dart not from universal_html.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the putData() method to send the image and set it's metadata as a image.

```
  Future<String> uploadImage(PlatformFile file) async {
    try {

      TaskSnapshot upload = await FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref(
              'events/${file.path}-${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}.${file.extension}')
          .putData(
            file.bytes,
            SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/${file.extension}'),
          );

      String url = await upload.ref.getDownloadURL();
      return url;
    } catch (e) {
      print('error in uploading image for : ${e.toString()}');
      return '';
    }
  }
```

putData() method takes Uint8List by default.

Answer (score 1):

Uploading images using TaskSnapshot is not working on my flutter web project.
I used firebase_storage: ^8.1.3 .
Following code is working for my web project.

```
String nameImage = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

Reference _reference = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('images/$nameImage.png}');
    await _reference
        .putData(
      await image.readAsBytes(),
      SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg'),
    )
        .whenComplete(() async {
      await _reference.getDownloadURL().then((value) {

        user.profilePictureURL = value;
        FireStoreUtils.firestore
          .collection(USERS)
          .doc(user.userID)
          .update({'profilePictureURL': user.profilePictureURL});

      });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can still use `.putFile` when you use the `File.fromUri()` constructor and get the `Uri` from the `PlatformFile` object using `Uri.dataFromBytes` and passing the bytes to it.

The code below contains changes that should remove the error:

```dart
    TaskSnapshot upload = await FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref(
            'events/${file.name}-${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}.${file.extension}')
        .putFile(File.fromUri(Uri.dataFromBytes(file.bytes.toList())));
```

Comment: Hey, It doesn't work. "Unsupported operation: Cannot extract a file path from a data URI" - This is the error i get. dart:io is not available for browser-based apps. That's why i can't use the File Object.